# The class of img tag doesn't work for correspond css file

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="store.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>About</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="navBar">
            <li><a href="http://csc412sfsu.com/~yzhang25/store_home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://csc412sfsu.com/~yzhang25/store_hours">Hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://csc412sfsu.com/~yzhang25/store_about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="centered-container">
            <h1 class="centered-text sansSerif-text">About the store</h1>
            <p>Here is the information about the store</p>
            <img class="open-sign-img" src="images/testpic.jpg" alt="open sign">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css files

```
.orange-text {
    color: orange;
}

.blue-text {
    color: blue;
}

#red-header {
    color: red;
}

.navBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.navBar li {
    display: inline;
}

.centered-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.centered-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.sansSerif-text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.centered-container .open-sign-img {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFi89.png)

the rest of my code works fine. In the chrome devTool it shows that the CSS class doesn't connect with the img tag in my html file. I am so confused, why the rest works except this one. I search a lot on goole but it seems I cant find out the correct answer.

Comment: It is showing up in the dev tools in this fiddle with nothing changed: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/0omj7r3d/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server that's serving your site currently sends the following headers along with your CSS file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 22:56:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 22:19:04 GMT
ETag: "22c-584296d30e600-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/css
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Due to the `Last-Modified` header the browser is going to cache this file to avoid having to request it from the server again. I have a feeling this is the issue in your case, as the site loads perfectly fine when I visit it right now.

If you don't want this to happen most browsers' developer tools have a checkbox that lets you disable caching while the tools are open.

In Chrome this can be found by opening the DevTools using F12, then clicking the Network tab, and checking "Disable cache". Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to do a hard reload that will force all cached assets to be re-requested without having to use the DevTools.

> [image: Screenshot of Google Chrome DevTools' Network tab with the Disable cache checkbox circled]

Comment: Thank you! It is the cache's problem

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle the css is correct:

with a background-color:

```
.centered-container .open-sign-img {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/4ug89r61](https://jsfiddle.net/4ug89r61/)

Did your clear your cache ?